# Google Indexing API 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, google-search-console

I have trouble setting up the Google Indexing API.

I guess I set all permissions, but it stills shows me a `403 Forbidden`-status.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2

SCOPES = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" ]
ENDPOINT = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"

# service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
JSON_KEY_FILE = "credits-6933.json"

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

# Define contents here as a JSON string.
# This example shows a simple update request.
# Other types of requests are described in the next step.

content = """{
  "url": "https://url.com/vanlife/",
  "type": "URL_UPDATED"
}"""

response, content = http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=content)
print(response.reason)
```

Did I miss something?
I read the posts here already, but did everything according to them - so no duplicate here.

URL and stuff is an example in my code.
Did I miss something?

[snipped from google services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIt4A.png)

[GSC snipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eulMO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and reading through several tutorials, I found my issue.

I didn't activate the API itself which is in my eyes, not described on the docs.

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=indexing.googleapis.com&credential=client_key

Followed this link and clicked on activate on the second tab. And it worked.

Comment: I am still getting a 403 error after I enabled the API this way. Any ideas?